# AWS Amplify Appsync Model — auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a `Team @model` with `@auth` settings. The `@model` also has an `admin` field that implies who has CRUD credentials. Here is the model:

```
type Team
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete] }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "admins", operations: [create, update, delete] }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "members", operations: [read, update] }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "viewers", operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  admins: [User!]!
  members: [User]
  viewers: [User]
  teamInfo: TeamInfo!
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}

type TeamInfo @model {
  id: ID!
  info: String
}
```

I have a few other tables, such as `TeamInfo` and others that are connected to the `Team @model`. How would the other tables inherit the `Team @auth` rules?